# How to merge two pandas dataframes/ series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, append, concatenation

I'm trying to merge multiple pandas data frames into one. I have 1 main frame with the locations of measurements. The other data frames contain multiple measurements for one location. Like below:

> df 1: Location ID | X | Y | Z
>
> ```
>        1        |1| 2 |3
>        2        |3| 2 |1
>        n
> ```
>
> df 2: Location ID |      Date         |  Measurement
>
> ```
>        1      |January 1  12:30  |      1
>        1      |January 16  12 :30 |     4
>        1              ...
> ```
>
> df 2: Location ID |      Date         |   Measurement
>
> ```
>        2      January 1  12:30        3
>        2      January 16  12 :30      9
>        2              ...
> ```
>
> df n: Location ID |      Date         |  Measurement
>
> ```
>        n      January 1  12:30        4
>        n      January 16 12 :30       6
>        n      January 20 11:30        7            ...
> ```

I'm trying to create a data frame like this:

> df_final: Location ID | X | Y | Z | january 1 12:00 |  January 16  12 :30|   January 20 11:30  etc.
>
> ```
>           1        1  2   3          1                  4             NaN
>           2        3  2   1          3                  9             NaN
>           n        2  5   7          4                  6             7
> ```

The dates are already datetime objects and the Location ID is the index of both dataframes.

I tried to use the append, the merge and the concat functions both using two frames and converting the frame to  a list by List = frame['measurements'] before adding it.

The problem is that either rows are added under the first data frame, while the measured values should be added in new columns on an existing row( the location ID resp.), or the dates end op to be new rows while new columns with location IDs are created.

I'm sorry my question lay-out is not so nice, but I'm new to this forum.

Comment: Not every Location will have measurements on every moment. I would like the frame to fill for columns without value a NaN and if the column is not present yet to add a new column. Preferably date sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself. 
I used frame. pivot to reshape df2-n and then used concat to ad it to the locations df.